# I am installing porto ultimate theme on my magento and it gives fatal error

Tags: magento

problem facing on installing porto ultimate theme

```
  Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Porto_Helper_Cssconfig' not found in C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\Mage.php on line 547 .
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you missed a file ? How are you installing the theme?

Comment: Upload all files again then clear cache...it is due to missing one of the file to upload.

Answer (score 1):

Mage_Porto_Helper_Cssconfig almost certainly does not exist (you can search for it in the code to confirm).

The fact that Magento is looking for the 3rd party file under the Mage namespace could indicate that there is a missconfiguration in the theme's config (either its etc/config.xml or its config in app/etc/local). It could also be that permissions or caching are preventing Magento from "seeing" the extension properly.